# Extending colouring of graphs using small number of colours

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings

> **Conjecture ([Csóka-Lippner-Pikhurko](https://doi.org/10.1017/fms.2016.22)).** If $G$ is a graph with each vertex of degree $\le d$ with at most $d-1$ pendant edges properly coloured, then this pre-colouring can be extended to all edges of $G$, using $d+1$ colours in total.
>
> If proved, this will directly give new bounds on questions of Albert (2010) & Marks (2016) on measurable Vizing's theorem.

(This problem was written 23.08.2018 by Oleg Pikhurko on [page 51](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewpage.php?vol=2&page=51) of [Volume 2](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewbook.php?vol=2) of the [Lviv Scottish Book](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka)).

Comment: I am confused. Do we colour edges or vertices? What are pending edges?

Comment: @FedorPetrov If I understood the problem correctly, we colour edges and pending edges are edges that contain a vertex of degree 1. But I will contact Oleg Pikhurko and will ask him to comment on this.

Comment: Still unclear. What are restrictions on the graph and what is already coloured?

Comment: @FedorPetrov I added the link (just after "Conjecture") to the original paper of Csoka-Lippner-Pikhurko (https://doi.org/10.1017/fms.2016.22). This conjecture is Conjecture 1.7. Definition 1.6 explains the terminology.

Answer (score 3):

The main motivation for us stating this conjecture was that, if the conjecture is true, then Vizing's theorem holds for every graphing. Since the latter result was recently proved by Jan Grebik and me (in https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.01716) via a different route, the conjecture is not so interesting now.